# How to use toLowerCase() in v-if in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In vue.js, I have the following code :

```
 <q-btn @click="goEditMode" color="primary" icon="edit" label="Edit"
     v-if="this.form.userName.toLowerCase() !== 'admin'" />
```

It occurs error after I adding **toLowerCase()**.

Here is the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"
```

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: I figured out the reason for this error is that the attribute `userName` of `this.form` has not been rendered yet, how to solve it based on this writting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v-if="this.form.userName && this.form.userName.toLowerCase() !== 'admin'" />
```

You can do this.

Answer (score 2):

you have to remove your `this.` in your template

```
v-if="form.userName.toLowerCase() !== 'admin'"
```

---

demo:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      query: 'oNe'
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app" class="demo">
  <div v-if="query.toLowerCase() !== 'one'">one</div>
  <div v-if="query.toLowerCase() !== 'two'">two</div>
</div>
```

demo2:

you can create a computed property to return a condition:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      role: 'aDmIn'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isAdmin() {
      if (this.role.toLowerCase() === 'admin') {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app" class="demo">
  <div v-if="isAdmin">is admin</div>
  <div v-if="!isAdmin">is user</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I have tried it, but the result is no difference

Comment: ok, strange - I added you an alternative solution via a `computed property`. This has the advantage that the template area looks cleaner and the logic is in the script area.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs due to `undefined.toLowerCase()`.

Looks like you are running `toLowerCase` on some property that is not present in its parent.

So check if `this.form.userName` is exists first.

You can perform something like this.

```
this.form.userName ? this.form.userName.toLowerCase() : ''
```

Comment: Yes, that's the question you are talking about，and how should I solve it? I just want to judge in `v-if`.